# Prove all rectificable functions on $[a,b]$ are integrable

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

> Let $f:[a,b]→R$ be a rectificable function (means that $\mathrm{Length}(f,[a,b])$ is finite), $[a,b]\subset\Bbb R$, prove that $f$ is integrable.

$\mathrm{Length}(f,[a,b])=\sup\{\mathrm{Length}(f,X):X\text{ partition of }[a,b]\}$

$\displaystyle\mathrm{Length}(f,X)=\sum_{i=1}^n\sqrt {(x_k-x_{k-1})^2 + \big(f(x_k)-f(x_{k-1})\big)^2}$

I tried to first prove that $f$ is bounded, so that I can prove $|f(x_k)-f(x_{k-1})|=\max(f(t_k))-\min(f(t_k)),t_k \in [x_{k-1},x_k]$, and use it with
$$\sqrt{\big(\max(f(t_k))-\min(f(t_k))\big)^2\!\!\cdot\!(x_k-x_{k-1})^2}<\sqrt {(x_k-x_{k-1})^2 + \big(f(x_k)-f(x_{k-1})\big)^2} - \frac{V}{n}$$
(where $V=\mathrm{Length}(f)$ for some finite real number $V$) to prove $f$ is integrable. However I don't know how to proceed in the last step.

Comment: What is your definition of rectifiable?

Comment: @KritikerderElche edited

Comment: @haha, what do you mean when you write $$\Delta (f(x_k)-f(x_{k-1}))^2*(x_k-x_{k-1})^2\;\;?$$What is “$\Delta$” and what is “$*$” ?

Comment: @Angelo I wrote $\Delta f_k$ as a shorthand and forgot to delete it.

Comment: @haha, what do you mean with the symbol “$*$” ? Do you mean a multiplication ?

Comment: @haha, are you sure that$$f(x_k)-f(x_{k-1})=\max(f(t_k))-\min(f(t_k)),t_k \in [x_{k-1},x_k]$$ is correct ?

Comment: @Angelo I think as long as $f$ is bounded, we can always add $t_k$ to $X$ to get $X'$. Is that not true? Also by "*" I did mean multiplication. I'm not good at formatting so that's just what I use.

Comment: @haha, I think that$$f(x_k)-f(x_{k-1})=\max(f(t_k))-\min(f(t_k)),t_k \in [x_{k-1},x_k]$$is false if the function $f$ is not monotonically increasing.

Comment: @Angelo You are right. I was thinking about using $(f(x_k)-f(x_{k-1})^2$ in my expression for upper minus lower Reimann sums, so I didn't pay close attention to the order.

Comment: @haha, but you should write$$|f(x_k)-f(x_{k-1})|\mathbf{\color{red}{\leqslant}}\max(f(t_k))-\min(f(t_k))$$instead of$$|f(x_k)-f(x_{k-1})|=\max(f(t_k))-\min(f(t_k))$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is rectificable, we have$$\sup\sum_{k=1}^{n}|f(x_{k})-f(x_{k-1})|\leq\sup\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sqrt{(x_{k}-x_{k-1})^{2}+(f(x_{k})-f(x_{k-1}))^{2}}<\infty.$$That is $f$ is a bounded variation function on $[a,b]$. Let$$\omega_{k}=\sup_{x_{k-1}\leq x\leq x_{k}}f(x)-\inf_{x_{k-1}\leq x\leq x_{k}}f(x),$$clearly$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\omega_{k}\leq\sup\sum_{k=1}^{n}|f(x_{k})-f(x_{k-1})|<\infty.$$Hence for each partition of $[a,b]$ we have $\lim\sum\omega_{k}\Delta x_{k}\to0$, which implies $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$.

Comment: Simple and clever approach. +1